# What is the Excel formula based on the value of a cell between a specific range of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am using `Excel 2016` and I need a formula for cell `W2` based on the value of cell `C2`, with the following logic:

```
if cell C2 is between 1 and 10, then it should output "R",
if cell C2 is between 11 and 20, then "B",
if cell C2 is between 21 and 30, then "Y",
if cell C2 is between 31 and 40, then, "G"
```

I am tinkering with the IF(AND..) formula but I am not getting it right.

This is what I have right now:

```
=IF(C2<=10,"R",IF(AND(C2>10,C2<=20,"B"),IF(AND(C2>20,C2<=30),"Y",IF(AND(C2>30,C2<=40),"G","!"))))
```

Comment: You could also start from higher values, using the order of evaluation to your advantage, i.e. if gt 30 return G, otherwise, if gt than 20 return Y, etc... Also, you could use a vlookup, rouding numbers to decades, which would avoid using deeply-nested if-else statements.

Comment: I've answered with almost the same formula. You forgot to close the bracket after 'C2<=20'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
=IF(C2<=10,"R",IF(AND(C2>10,C2<=20),"B",IF(AND(C2>20,C2<=30),"Y",IF(AND(C2>30,C2<=40),"G","!"))))
```

You can always double-check functions by double-click on the function suggestions and see if you used all brackets correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should do something like this instead (e.g. using [VLOOKUP](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)):

```
=VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C2, -1), $C$4:$D$7, 2, FALSE)
```

Where

[image]

which avoids the use of deeply-nested if-else statements. I mean, what are you going to do if you need to do so for 20 letters? A 20-level nested if-else statement? No.

Answer (score 2):

Short:

```
=CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(C2/10,0),"R","B","Y","G")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Classical IF AND

```
=IF(C2<=10,"R",IF(AND(C2>10,C2<=20),"B",IF(AND(C2>20,C2<=30),"Y",IF(AND(C2>30,C2<=40),"G","!"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original formula suffers from a common problem, The IF statement 'short-circuits'; that is to say that once one of the nested IF conditions is true, no further nested calculation is made. If the first IF is passed over then the second IF does not need to check if C2 is greater than 10; in fact, it **has** to be >10 or the second IF would never have been reached. This logic follows through to the remaining nested IFs.

```
=IF(C2<=10, "R", IF(C2<=20, "B" , IF(C2<=30, "Y", IF(C2<=40, "G", "!"))))
```

Note that your narrative states *'if cell C2 is between 1 and 10, then it should output "R"'* but your formula evaluates the simpler *'less than or equal to 10'* which also covers zero and negative numbers.

You can also 'hard code' a lookup.

```
=LOOKUP(C2, {-1E+99,1,11,21,31,41}, {"!","R","B","Y","G","!"})
```